# Kenmore double oven door has 120v at the handle

Tags: oven, ground

Randomly, the other day I was cooking in my double oven. I reached up to open it and the door handle shocked me.  I checked and as soon as I hit the button to turn on the oven, the door gets electrified. I opened the panel and didn't notice anything weird. I checked the heating element, and it is fine. The oven heats up and works as normal, but something is sending electricity through the machine.  Seems to be some sort of ground issue? This is a Kenmore 790.48763900. It happens when I turn either of the ovens on, but it's not hot when the oven is not on. The breaker can be on, and the oven is not hot.  Can anyone point me to something I can check?

Comment: Sounds like classic lost neutral to me, but could be short circuit. Obviously stop using the appliance and turn off the circuit breaker until someone who knows what they are doing can safely diagnose and repair the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a lost neutral. Get a good quality multimeter, minimum CAT II [like this Klein](https://amzn.to/43nn5jV) (you do **not** want to do testing on 120V/240V with unknown junk). Ideally you want to test a 120V/240V connection like a dryer receptacle (if you have an electric dryer) - you should get ~ 120V from each hot to neutral, each hot to ground (same number in both), either 2x that (240V) or a bit less (208V in some configurations) hot-hot, 0V neutral-ground. If you have a variance - e.g., 150V and 90V *and in particular if it changes when you turn the oven or other 240V*

Comment: *appliances on/off* then you have a house (panel or utility feed) problem, likely a lost neutral. On the other hand, if voltages everywhere (except your oven door) check out normal then you have a **fault in your oven**, likely combined with **3-wire old-style connection instead of a proper separate ground wire**. That could be a fault with wiring or could be a fault with the oven itself, such that some of the current used by the element (240V so could be either hot leg) is faulting to ground or is faulting to neutral *but ground and neutral are bonded, which is bad*.

Answer (score 3):

### Turn the oven breaker OFF until it is fixed.

This is the standard failure mode of "3-wire" dryers and ranges when the neutral wire breaks.  The chassis is electrified, and it kills someone. No joke.

Loss of the neutral wire breaks the oven light, clock, and sometimes controls.

Starting in 1954, they started requiring grounds and by 1965 they were required on all circuits.  Except that dryer and range manufacturers complained, and cable manufacturers would be stuck with un-saleable cables, so they compromised on allowing ungrounded connections to ranges and dryers only.  The chassis was "grounded" to neutral on the logic that this socket is rarely disturbed and so, unlikely to fail.   This did not work, and in 1996 was banned. (By which time, ungrounded /3 cable had been out of production for 30 years, and /3+ground was the normal option anyway).

If the range had a 4-wire connection, this electric shock would be impossible (or require a really bizarre failure).

### What to do

In the short term, you can repair that neutral wire connection and you should be right as rain, at least according to 1965 safety sensibilities. However, you can guess we're going to advise an upgrade of both range and dryer to a less dangerous connection.  This isn't necessarily hard.

- If the cable from panel to range is already. 4-wire, a 4-wire connection can simply be wired. If socketed, use a NEMA 14-50 cord and socket (14-30 for dryer). Follow the range's instructions to remove the bootleg bonding wire that connects ground to neutral.
- If the existing cable is "/2+ground" cable, it was illegal the day it was installed and must be replaced entirely.
- if it is practical to run a #10 bare ground wire from the range to anywhere that has a #10 or larger ground wire back to the panel, then ground can be retrofit, and a 4-wire connection can be used.
- if it is not practical to run a ground, the 3-wire connection using 4-wire hardware (e.g. NEMA 14-50 socket) **and connecting ground to absolutely nothing**.  A GFCI breaker at the panel is required to use this method. Any socket needs to be labeled "GFCI Protected - No  Equipment Ground".

Comment: Key to any of these fixes is to **remove the neutral/ground bond from the oven**.